# Timer-app running in the background Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, timer, swift3

Im trying to develop a timer app for cooking. The maximum time-length is 20 minutes. The problem is that I don't want the timer-operation terminated if the user hit the home button.

I've read about background modes (https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial)
Which is helpful but I still don't know which method is the most appropriate. Also I read that the maximum length of running a app in background-mode is 3 minutes. Is that really the case?

I'm grateful for all the help I can get.

Comment: If your app moves to the background then the best you can do is schedule a local notification for delivery at the time that the timer will expire.  If the app returns to the foreground before then, you can cancel the notification and resume your timer. (If you aren't going to submit the app to the store then you can misuse the audio background mode by "playing" silence)

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: So I'll save a notification for a specific time based on the amount of time left on the timer. If the user opens the app again update the the remaining time, and in that case I don't need to run the app in background-mode, is that correct?

Comment: That's correct.